# In Visual GDB, how to set to break when a variable is changed?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Somehow the contents of ReadEncoder is being changed.
Can we set a "write-breakpoint" on the memory address ?

Using C, programming an Embedded MicroController under Visual GDB

Comment: yes you can: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/data-breakpoints-15-8-update/

Comment: Cant make it work, using " C "  not sure thats supported...
I am programming a microController using GDB

Comment: Visual Studio and GDB are two very different things. Please fix your question title. GDB has a "watch" command, read the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

Answer (score 0):

after reading the manual,

I had to open the GDB console and enter this command:

```
watch ReadEncoder
```

GDB returned :

```
watch ReadEncoder 
&"watch ReadEncoder \n"
Hardware watchpoint 5: ReadEncoder
=breakpoint-created,bkpt={number="5",type="hw watchpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",what="ReadEncoder",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="ReadEncoder"}
OK
```

and it worked!
it trapped a pointer out of bounds over writing stuff.
exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

The other method is to set a "Data Breakpoint" in Visual Studio.

Pause execution

Debug -> Windows -> Breakpoints -> New data breakpoint
enter "ReadEncoder" there

and that worked too. ( as per the original question)